# node.js callback design - how to use res in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a route that do some processing than it should return a callback. 
here is the code:

```
router.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
  // send call to login function.
  var ID= req.query.ID;
  var Password = req.query.Password 

  ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, LoginCallback);



});

function LoginCallback(err,myLoginResult)
{
  res.json(myLoginResult);
}
```

The Login function check if the user/pass exists in the database and returns:

```
loginCallback(result);
```

My question - the LoginCallBack fucntion does not know the object res. 
I know I can transfer it to the login module just to have it passed back to me as a parameter to callback function, but it seems like a bad design, it's bad enough I need to send the callback function to the login method.

Is there a better way to do it, and still have readable code ?

Comment: *"it's bad enough I need to send the callback function to the login method"* Why is that?

Comment: To work a-synchronously I guess.

Comment: What I meant was, why do you think callbacks are bad design? They're fairly standard, but if you want an alternative you could return a promise.

Comment: Callback are heaviky used in javascript. I think it is overuse. But I accept it is the efficient way to program in node environment. The code is harder to read though.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I would use in your case (if we skip using Promises and other harder stuff) is binding a function to context. 
Most often it's used to preserve object context when using object methods as callbacks but also it can be used to create a function with fewer arguments than original one (sometimes referred as *currying*).

In javascript you can bind context using method `bind` on any function. The first parameter is a value of `this` during function call and others are just argument values.

Your code rewrote using `bind`:

```
router.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
  // send call to login function.
  var ID= req.query.ID;
  var Password = req.query.Password 

  ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, LoginCallback.bind(null, res));
});

function LoginCallback(res, err, myLoginResult)
{
  res.json(myLoginResult);
}
```

```

Comment: Clean way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I think The best approach is to use this snippet of code :

```
    ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, function(myLoginResult){

           res.json(myloginResult);

    });
```

In this case you should have in your login function something like this :

```
    login(ID, Password, callback){
        //your treatment here 
         callback(result)


     }
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid this nested form for coding - as it grows deeper and deeper. I though my version is equal but I guess it is not...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own middleware to handle your login on a different function. Here is a simple express app I created for you:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

function login(req, res, next) {
    // login check
    console.log(req.query);
    if(req.query.ID === '1' && req.query.Password === 'password') {
        return next();
    }

    // if check above is false
    res.send({success: false});
}

app.get('/login', login, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({success: true});
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

You can see that I inserted the function in the post route `app.get('/login', login, func...`.

Now if you visit the page with these url parameters http://localhost:3000/login?ID=1&Password=password you should see the success message. If you change any of the parameter names or values, it should return success: false.

You should read more on making your own [Express Custom Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are using loginCallback out of scope of function(req,res,next) so as req, res and next are out of scope they can not accessed. you can have access to this like

```
router.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
  // send call to login function.
  var ID= req.query.ID;
  var Password = req.query.Password 

  function LoginCallback(err,myLoginResult){
    res.json(myLoginResult);
  }

  ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, LoginCallback);
});
```

or if ctlLogin function suport promise you can use promise instead of callback

```
ctlLogin.login(ID,Password)
   .then(LoginCallback)
   .catch(console.log(err))
```

or if you want LoginCallback function out of scope of function(req,res,next) then you need to pass res in that function by creating a callback function and then call LoginCallback function by passing error, results and res or by use bind.

```
function sendResponseToSever(res, err, myLoginResult){
   if(err){
         return res.send({ 
              errors: err,
              status: 500 // what ever status code you want to set
         }); 
   }
    return res.json(results);
 }

   router.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
     // send call to login function.
     var ID= req.query.ID;
     var Password = req.query.Password       

     ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, sendResponseToSever.bind(null, res)   
         //using bind function
        // OR 
     ctlLogin.login(ID,Password, function(err, myLoginResult){
         sendResponseToSever(err, myLoginResult, res);
        // now sendResponseToSever is a generic function which you can call 
        // from any route
     });          
   });
});
```

But most preferred way is use of promises if you want to avoid callback hell. 
As you mentioned you want to avoid nesting you can avoid it by using promises.

please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise if you want to learn promises

Answer (score 1):

This can be restructured easily into more `readable` code using promises with very little refactoring:

```
router.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
  // send call to login function.
  var ID= req.query.ID;
  var Password = req.query.Password 

  ctlLogin.login(ID,Password)
      .then((result) => {
         // handle success
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         // handle failure
      })
});



function Login(ID, password) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        // run your query using a library that supports promises
        .then((result) => resolve(result))
        .catch((err) => {
            //handle your error
            reject(err)
        })
    }
}
```